# Why does setUseSystemMenuBar() get ignored when I have a SplashScreen-Image in my jar?

Tags: java, macos, javafx

I want to display a splash screen image for my JavaFX application. I've done this previously for a Swing application by setting:

```
SplashScreen-Image: splash.png
```

in the MANIFEST.MF of the applications jar file. As described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) the splash screen will not automatically close as I'm not displaying a Swing/AWT window. So I'm closing it manually:

```
    final SplashScreen splash = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();
    if (splash != null) 
    {
        splash.close();
    }
```

The issue is the menu bar of my JavaFX application does not go in the system menu bar, its attached to the application, even though I'm requesting it does:

```
menuBar.setUseSystemMenuBar(true);
```

If I remove SplashScreen-Image from the jar's MANIFEST.MF the menu bar is displayed as expected.

I've looked at using a [Preloader](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/preloaders.htm) to do this but have discounted this because:

- I don't need any feedback as the app is launching, I just want to display simple logo
- The SplashScreen-Image comes up really quickly, before the JVM starts. Using a Preloader still requires the JVM to start to display it

Is this a bug in Java? Is there another approach I could take that would work just as well as I'm used to with my Swing appliaction?

I've got a demo maven project [here](https://github.com/liamsharp/splash-screen-image-bug). You'll need to edit the pom to include/exclude the SplashScreen-Image from the jar.

Comment: I ran into the same thing...ever find a solution?

Comment: Nope - I'm going to raise a bug at some point..

Comment: Got similar problem. Thank you for discovering that it's flash screen issue. Disabling flash fixed it. Did you file a bug? If so, I'd appreciate the link.